# Xcode iOS 6 - UITableView Null on Navigating Back using Storyboard

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios6, uistoryboard, back

In my iOS app I am using a UITableView which is populated correctly on launch and I navigate to a subview using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSubView" sender:self];
}
```

When the subview loads I can access the UITableView but when I navigate back using the back button on the navigation bar I want to update the table before it becomes visible to the user. I am trying to update the table in viewWillDisappear but myTableView is NULL for some reason:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[_myTableView reloadData];
}
```

I have declared myTableView in the header file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

Everything is referenced correctly and all View Controllers have the same class "ViewController" so I can't understand why this isn't working! Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewWillDisapear`.  `viewDidDisappear` won't be called until after the view is no longer visible.